# C# Using child class methods on an array of objects

Tags: c#

I'm sure I'm missing something minor but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm trying to use the child class method CalculateInterest for child class SavingsAccount and the child class property TransactionFee for the child class CheckingAccount in the below script. Basically, the test program should loop through each object in the array and depending upon whether the object is a CheckingAccount or SavingsAccount state the interest earned or the transaction fee charged.

The error I get is that CalculateInterest() and TransactionFee are not defined in class Account.

```
using System;

class BankAccountTester {

    static void Main() {

    Account[] accounts = new Account[4];
    accounts[0] = new SavingsAccount(25, 3);    
    accounts[1] = new CheckingAccount(80, 1);
    accounts[2] = new SavingsAccount(200, 1.5);
    accounts[3] = new CheckingAccount(400, 0.5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            double amount;
            string entryString;
            bool check = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to withdraw from Account " + i );
            entryString = Console.ReadLine();
            check = double.TryParse(entryString, out amount);

            while (check == false) {

                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry. Please specify an amount to withdraw from Account " + i);
                entryString = Console.ReadLine();
                check = double.TryParse(entryString, out amount);

            }

            accounts[i].Debit(amount);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to deposit into Account " + i);
            entryString = Console.ReadLine();
            check = double.TryParse(entryString, out amount);

            while (check == false) {

                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry. Please specify an amount to deposit into Account " + i);
                entryString = Console.ReadLine();
                check = double.TryParse(entryString, out amount);

            }

            accounts[i].Credit(amount);

            if (accounts[i] is SavingsAccount) {

                Console.WriteLine("This is a savings account.");

                double interestEarned = accounts[i].CalculateInterest();

                Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} interest to Account {2} (Savings Account)", interestEarned, i);

            }

            else {

                Console.WriteLine("This is a checking account.");

                Console.WriteLine("{0} transaction fee charged.", accounts[i].TransactionFee);

            } 


        }

    }

}

class Account {

    private double balance;

    public double Balance { 

        get {

            return balance;

        }

        set {

            if (value<0) {
                balance = 0;
            }

            else balance = value;

        }

    }

    public Account(double initBalance) {

        Balance = initBalance;

    }

    public void Credit(double amount) {

        Balance = Balance + amount;

    }

    public void Debit(double amount) {

        if (amount>Balance) {

            Console.WriteLine("Amount exceeds account balance.");

        }
        else Balance = Balance - amount;

    }

}

class SavingsAccount : Account {

    private double interestRate;
    private double interestEarned;

    public SavingsAccount(double initBalance, double interest) : base(initBalance) {

        interestRate = interest/100;

    }

    public double CalculateInterest() {

            interestEarned = Balance*interestRate;
            return interestEarned;

    }
}

class CheckingAccount : Account {

    private double transactionFee;

    public double TransactionFee {

        get {
            return transactionFee;
        }

        set {
            transactionFee = value;
        }
    }

    public CheckingAccount(double initBalance, double fee) : base(initBalance) {

        TransactionFee = fee;

    } 

    public new void Credit(double amount) {

        Balance = Balance + amount;
        Balance = Balance - TransactionFee;

    }

    public new void Debit(double amount) {

        bool check;

        if (amount>Balance) {

            Console.WriteLine("Amount exceeds account balance.");
            check = false;

        }
        else {

            Balance = Balance - amount;
            check = true;
        }

        if (check == true) {
            Balance = Balance - TransactionFee;
        }
        else Balance = Balance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you inherit `Account` to hide (`new`) its methods? Ever heard of the `virtual` and `override` modifiers?

Comment: The type of objects in your `accounts` list is `Account`, which does not have those methods.

Comment: If I use an if statement though to check and see if an object in the array is a SavingsAccount or a CheckingAccount it comes back correct though?

Comment: What a strange bank that pays a flat percentage of interest without any time component, and which charges you for making a deposit...

Comment: Rufus. I'm a student writing this script in response to a question on an assignment. You're response is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the objects to the more specialized type first, before you can use the methods:

Change this:

```
double interestEarned = accounts[i].CalculateInterest();
```

To this:

```
double interestEarned = ((SavingsAccount)accounts[i]).CalculateInterest();
```

Change this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} transaction fee charged.", accounts[i].TransactionFee);
```

To this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} transaction fee charged.", ((CheckingAccount)accounts[i]).TransactionFee);
```

Comment: This compiles without issue but I get a runtime error when the program get to this code:

Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: That's the formatting string on the next line. Look at the indices, it should be `{0}` and `{1}`: `Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} interest to Account {2} (Savings Account)",`.

Comment: You're so right! That was  rookie mistake on my part, thanks!

Comment: I strenuously don't recommend this. It will compile. But by hiding methods with `new`, if you cast the object as one type it will call one method, but if you cast it as a different type you get a different method. Instead, make the method in the base class `virtual`. Then you can override it in inherited classes. If the inherited class wants to do the same thing as the base class but just add more functionality, the inherited class can call the base class method and then do its own thing.

Comment: Or, if you want to have some real fun - turn in the assignment with the hidden/`new` methods. If the instructor doesn't notice and question them, don't trust anything he/she tells you from then on. Just get through the class the best you can and don't look back.